# Как сделать, учитывая високосный год?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

HTML:

```
<select name='day' id='day'>
    <option selected='selected' disabled='disabled'>День</option>
    <?php
        for($day = 1; $day <= 31; $day++){
        echo "<option value=\"". $day ."\">$day</option>\n"; } ?>
    </select>
    <select name='month' id='month'>
    <option selected='selected' disabled='disabled'>Месяц</option>
               <?php
                    for($month = 1; $month <= 12; $month++){
                        switch($month){
                            case 1: $month_name = "января"; break;
                            case 2: $month_name = "февраля"; break;
                            case 3: $month_name = "марта"; break;
                            case 4: $month_name = "апреля"; break;
                            case 5: $month_name = "мая"; break;
                            case 6: $month_name = "июня"; break;
                            case 7: $month_name = "июля"; break;
                            case 8: $month_name = "августа"; break;
                            case 9: $month_name = "сентября"; break;
                            case 10: $month_name = "октября"; break;
                            case 11: $month_name = "ноября"; break;
                            case 12: $month_name = "декабря"; }
                        echo "<option value=\"". $month."\"> $month_name</option>\n"; }?>
    </select>
<select name='year' id='year'>
<option selected='selected' disabled='disabled'>Год</option>
                <?php
                for($year = date("Y") - 80; $year <= date("Y"); $year++){
                    echo "<option value=\"". $year ."\">$year</option>\n";}?>
</select>
```

JS:

```
$("#year").change = $("#month").change(function(){
    var year = document.getElementById('year').value,
        month = document.getElementById('month').value,
        md = (new Date(year, month, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)).getDate();

    var select = document.getElementById('day');
        select.options.length = 0;

    for (var i = 1; i <= md; i++){
        var option = document.createElement('OPTION');
            option.innerHTML = option.value = i;
            select.appendChild(option);
    }
});
```

Собственно, как сделать, чтобы был учёт високосного года при выборе месяца и года?

Comment: Напрашивается вариант - при изменении пользователем года или месяца пересоздавать select с нужным списком дней. Для всех месяцев кроме февраля можно из фиксированного массива брать кол-во дней, для февраля вычислять относительно выбранного года - days = (((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) || (year % 400 == 0)) ? 29 : 28;

Comment: А разве ваш код сейчас не учитывает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем-то ваш код вполне рабочий. Нет возможности проверить оригинальный php вариант, поэтому вот переписанная немного js-only реализация:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <select name='day' id='day'>
    <option selected='selected' disabled='disabled'>День</option>
  </select>

  <select name='month' id='month'>
    <option selected='selected' disabled='disabled' value='0'>Месяц</option>
    <option value="1">января</option>
    <option value="2">февраля</option>
    <option value="3">марта</option>
    <option value="4">мая</option>
    <option value="5">июня</option>
    <option value="6">июля</option>
    <option value="7">августа</option>
    <option value="8">сентября</option>
    <option value="9">октября</option>
    <option value="10">февраля</option>
    <option value="11">ноября</option>
    <option value="12">декабря</option>
  </select>

  <select name='year' id='year'>
    <option selected='selected' disabled='disabled' value='0'>Год</option>
    <option value="2015">2015</option>
    <option value="2016">2016</option>
    <option value="2017">2017</option>
    <option value="2018">2018</option>
    <option value="2019">2019</option>
    <option value="2020">2020</option>
    <option value="2021">2021</option>
  </select>

  <script>
    var updateDays = function() {
      var year = document.getElementById('year').value || 2015,
        month = document.getElementById('month').value || 1,
        md = new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();

      var select = document.getElementById('day');
      select.options.length = 1;
      for (var i = 1; i <= md; i++) {
        var option = document.createElement('OPTION');
        option.innerHTML = option.value = i;
        select.appendChild(option);
      }
    };
    updateDays();
    $("#month").change(updateDays);
    $("#year").change(updateDays);
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Возможно у вас падал скрипт из-за того, что не был выбран год или месяц в момент расчета кол-ва дней. Для исправления добавлены значения для дефолтных опций.